# Using PHP global variable inside yml file

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I'm trying to use the `$_SERVER` global variable inside the yml file but I cant find anywhere how to do it with PHP. All the online examples to doing so are for ruby. Is it possible with PHP?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the server variables the same way you would with `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

```
$request->server->get('YOUR_VARIABLE') // For a specific $_SERVER variable

$request->server->all()                // For all $_SERVER variables
```

**UPDATE:**

To get them in the config files you could do the following (taken from an Openshift Symfony2 distribution - https://github.com/hasinhayder/openshift-symfony-2.3.0/tree/master/php/app/config)

Set your parameters in a php file, in the example above it's called `params.php`

```
<?php
$container->setParameter('parameter_one', $_SERVER['parameter_one']);
```

Then include that in your config.yml file

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: params.php }
```

And then you should just be able to use them as if they had been set in a regular linked yml file like

```
%parameter_one%
```

Comment: but I want to do so inside the yml file

Comment: I'm a little confused about this.  Are you suggesting he download that package to which you linked? If not, how does $container->setParameter() relate to this?  If one isn't using that package, how would they go about setting the PHP variables so that the YML can make use of them?

Comment: For more info see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html#miscellaneous-configuration

Comment: How come this got a down vote after 3 years? Is it no longer applicable to Symfony 2.3?

Answer (score -3):

If you're not making a government site of some sort, why not use `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE`?

```
<?php
    $expire=time()+60*60*24*30; //About a month
    setcookie("user", "John", $expire);
?>
```

Access with `$_COOKIE['user']`

For the `$_SERVER` variable, click [here](http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/7-php-server-example-list)
. Don't exactly know what you want to do with it though.

Comment: because this is system has multiple sites and if some user running two sites simultaneously the cookie will give me bad data.
further more, if i knew how to access cookie i could access server.. but if i use $COOKIE['user'] what i get is a string contains $COOKIE['user']

Comment: I don't think this really addresses OP's question