# How to get in config.yml the domain name?

Tags: php, symfony, config, domain-name

I want to access in my `config.yml` to the domain name of my web site.

> Example: www.site1.com => I want to get site1.com

So I don't know if exist variables like `%kernel.something%` which return the domaine name and if they don't exist how can I get this in my config.yml ?

Comment: The answer : 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219946/using-php-global-variable-inside-yml-file][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219946/using-php-global-variable-inside-yml-file

Answer (score 0):

As @DOZ says, you have to create php file, say `param.php`:

```
$container->setParameter('domain_name', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Put `param.php` in `app/config` directory.

Then you need to import `param.php` in `app/config/config.yml`:

```
imports:
# ...
- { resource: param.php }
```

Now you can use your parameter in `config.yml` as `%domain_name%`.

Comment: but there is a BIG pb : param.php is loaded into Symfony cache. So the request changes are not considered.. you have to delete the cache manually using `rm -rf app/cache/*` And I don't know how to arround this problem...