# Symfony : Can't clear cache when using PHP global variable inside config.yml

Tags: php, console, environment-variables, symfony

in my `config.yml` file, I import a `params.php` file which configures a parameter :

```
// app/config/params.php

<?php
$container->setParameter('base_name', $_SERVER['BASE']);
```

I use this parameter for VichUploader configuration :

```
// app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: params.php }

vich_uploader:
   db_driver: orm
   mappings:
        tag_image:
            uri_prefix:         %base_name%/../images/tags
```

It works well in my project but I have an error when I want to clear cache :

```
$ php bin/console cache:clear
```

[image]

I use Symfony3.
I followed the guidelines of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219946/using-php-global-variable-inside-yml-file).

Comment: What is that $_SERVER['BASE']? Can't you use an env variable instead?

Comment: Probably you will incur in this error with each console command where the $_SERVER variable doesn't exists. I suggest you to take a look at the official doc about [How to Set external Parameters in the Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html)

Comment: I've already seen this documentation and I proceed like in the second paragraph "Miscellaneous Configuration". I will try to configure a virtual host. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just about not getting errors in cli mode, you could just modify your `params.php` this way

```
// app/config/params.php

<?php
if (php_sapi_name() != "cli") {
    $container->setParameter('base_name', $_SERVER['BASE']);
}
```

IMO, if you want to set external parameters, here is the way you should do it http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html

Comment: I've already seen this documentation and I proceed like in the second paragraph "Miscellaneous Configuration". You're solution works, I just added an "else" condition to set base_name with an empty string because, if not, I have an error "non-existent parameter base_name".

I will try the solution with the virtual host but you're solution works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The "BASE" key dont exists when you call a script in the console. You need to check first if this key exists in you params.php. I dont know the vich uploader bundle but i think you dont need a proper config on the cache clear command. So if the base key dont exists, i think you could set an empty string as config.